# Как можно интегрировать свою программу на Python в Windows 10

Tags: python, csv, импорт

Сейчас моя программа может получить в себя файл и его путь если я перетаскиваю его на готовый экзешник. Я думал что "Открыть с помощью..." будет работать так же но программа не сохраняет файл ,а просто закрывается.
Код импорта:

```
import sys
import csv

impfilename = sys.argv[1]
with open(impfilename, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
```

Код экспорта:

```
filename = input('Имя файла:')
with open('{}'.format(filename)+'.csv', "w", newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(lest)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962157/open-with-a-file-on-windows-with-a-python-application